# React npm package: Do I need a different webpack config to be ssr safe?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I maintain a small npm package and I am currently trying to use it in a Gatsby site. I am not a webpack expert and I am struggling to make my npm package ssr safe.

Currently, if I try `gatsby build` it will throw the following error:

`failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.829s
WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  window.addEventListener( 'click', this.onClickCloseMenu, false );
}
```

I added the following file to my package:

```
// allows us to use window server-side
const safeWindow = (typeof window === 'undefined') ? {
    addEventListener() {},
    removeEventListener() {},
  } : window;

export default safeWindow;
```

and imported the object in my code:

```
import safeWindow from './safeWindow';
...
    componentDidMount = () => {
        safeWindow.addEventListener( 'click', this.onClickCloseMenu, false );
    }
```

But unfortunately this didn't help. I was already using window only in useEffect/componentDid(Un)Mount but I guessed since it was a compilation error that I needed to define it. My next guess is that building/minifying my package to publish it to npm broke this again but I am not sure.

This is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/DataListInput.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('lib'),
        filename: 'DataListInput.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /^(?!.*?\.module).*\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Find the npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datalist-input)

**UPDATE**

I am pretty sure now that it has something todo with webpack bundling css together with javascript in the minified file which requires calls to both window and document. Does someone has experienced something similar? How do I solve this issue?

**UPDATE 2**

I resolved the issue by removing the css. I created a new ssr safe npm package without css. It feels more like a work-around than a solution, so I am still interested if there is a way to bundle css + javascript and be ssr compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `safeWindow` from a constant into a `getSafeWindow` function should fix it.

A constant is evaluated before the module can be imported. While a function version will only access window when it is called at runtime.

```
const getSafeWindow = () => (typeof window === 'undefined') ? {
    addEventListener() {},
    removeEventListener() {},
  } : window;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will try it out! Any idea why `if(typeof window !== 'undefined') window.addEventListener()` inside my componentDidMount function failed? I feel like it should have worked with this reasoning.

Comment: I checked gatsby's issues and I agree that putting it in componentDidMount should work. Perhaps you were still importing safeWindow and it was failing for that?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my webpack config, even if I remove all setTimeouts/addEventListeners from the code and use webpack, it will still contain mentions of window in the build. So I guess I have to tweak the config for that.

Comment: You could try targeting node in webpack config but that might cause other problems: `
module.exports = {
  target: 'node'
};
`

Comment: Perhaps your webpack config is bundling react and react dom. Maybe you could make them externals: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275

Comment: Thanks for your support. It threw react not found, but using this instead worked: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275#issuecomment-225644823 but I am still getting the same window undefined error by Gatsby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212831/discussion-between-will-and-andre).